# epoll and multiple processes

Tags: sockets, server, epoll

Assume, I have a process that binds to a socket, than forks himself to create 4 instances of the current process.

New processes inherit the file descriptor of the parent socket and are able to do an "accept" on it. If I put the socket descriptor into epoll and try to connect to the socket, all 4 workers are being notified (EPOLLIN) there is some data to read/accept. all workers try to do an accept 3 of them fail and only one can do accept.

How can I get around this behaviour?
This is too big performance penalty letting most of the workers to fail every time on incomming connection.

How this can be avoided?

Comment: Only have one process touch any given socket. In fact, close() the other sockets.

Comment: Why do you want to have four processes listen on the same socket anyway?  The typical pattern is to have one process that listens and accepts incoming connections, then forks a worker child to handle the individual connection (*not* the listening socket).

Answer (score 0):

If `accept()` returns -1/EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN, just return to the poll loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use EPOLLONESHOT while adding sockets in epoll fd which should notify only one process for one event.

Or you can safeguard epoll fd so that only one worker waits on epoll fd.

Answer (score 0):

This is thundering herd issue which can be solved by using EPOLLEXCLUSIVE flag. That would ensure that only one waiting process is woken up per event.